# Append to nested array swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, userdefaults

Might be an easy question for the experts but as a newbie I'm struggling to figure this out and confusing myself so I thought I would just post it here. What I would like to do is create a nested array when this Add button is pressed. I would like to build a list of "selections" to store in UserDefaults under each "id". I've simplified the code but I already have "id" and "selection" being called in from elsewhere, so those variables are working, I just need to know how to add the selection to list of selections under the id. I hope this makes sense. 1 id, list of many selections.

Code below that I've been working with, found through [this tutorial](https://cocoacasts.com/ud-4-how-to-store-a-dictionary-in-user-defaults-in-swift)

```
@State var id = ""
@State var selection = ""
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

Button(action: {
    userDefaults.set(dictionary, forKey: "myKey")
    var strings: [String:String] = userDefaults.object(forKey: "myKey") as? [String:String] ?? [:]
    strings[id] = selection
    userDefaults.set(strings, forKey: "myKey")
    }) { 
    Text("Add") 
   }
```

Comment: What is your definition of a nested array?  And what does your `userDefaults` contains?

Comment: @El Tomato, I would like to store something like ‘id1: [selection1, selection3, selection5], id2:[selection1, selection2]’ I will then do a check on the view to see what selections user has made for that specific view (id) and show a “Remove” button. So on view id1 the selections 1, 3, and 5 will have Remove buttons